# Create deployment using ShrinkWrap in abstract class using Arquillian and ShrinkWrap

Tags: java, jpa, jboss-arquillian, shrinkwrap

I am trying to performing tests by define an abstract class, which will create a common deployment for each test using Arquillian and ShrinkWrap. In my repositories, I have an EntityManager, which performs the JPA operations. The UserRepository and CarRepository is identical (except for User and Car). Same for UserRepositoryTest and CarRepositoryTest.

However, the CarRepositoryTest generate an error of some reason. Can you please help me? =)

```
public abstract class AbstractRepositoryTest {

        @Inject
        protected UserRepository userRepository;

        @Inject
        protected GroupRepository groupRepository;

        @Inject
        protected CarRepository carRepository;

        protected DummyGenerator dg;

        protected UserRepositoryFindQuery qUser;

        protected CarRepositoryFindQuery qCar;

        @Deployment
        public static final Archive<?> createDeployment() {

                File[] libs = Maven
                                .resolver()
                                .loadPomFromFile("pom.xml")
                                .resolve("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3",
                                                "org.fluttercode.datafactory:datafactory",
                                                "org.dbunit:dbunit",
                                                "mysql:mysql-connector-java",
                                                "org.slf4j:slf4j-api",
                                                "org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14")
                                .withTransitivity().asFile();

                return ShrinkWrap
                                .create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")
                                .addAsLibraries(libs)
                                .addPackage(User.class.getPackage())
                                .addPackage(UserRepository.class.getPackage())
                                .addPackage(DummyGenerator.class.getPackage())
                                .addAsResource("test-persistence.xml",
                                                "META-INF/persistence.xml")
                                .addAsResource("database-test-setup.xml", "database-test-setup.xml")           
                                .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
        }

        @Before
        public void setUp() throws Exception {
                resetDatabase();
                dg = new DummyGenerator();
                qUser = new UserRepositoryFindQuery();
                qCar = new CarRepositoryFindQuery();
        }

// ..
}

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class CarRepositoryTest extends AbstractRepositoryTest {

        @Test
        public void testIsDeployed() {
                Assert.assertNotNull(carRepository);
        }

        @Test
        public void testCreateNewCar() throws Exception {
                Car car = dg.getCar();
                User user = dg.getUser();

                car.modifyUser(user);

                // Execute
                Car createdCar = carRepository.create(car);
                assertNotNull(createdCar);

                // Verify
                qCar.addToRegistrationNumberCriteria(dg.getLastCars().get(0).getRegistrationNumber());
                carRepository.find(qCar);

                assertEquals(1, qCar.getResult().size());
                assertEquals(dg.getLastCars().get(0), qCar.getResult().get(0) );

        }
// ..
}

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class UserRepositoryTest extends AbstractRepositoryTest {

        @Test
        public void testIsDeployed() {
                Assert.assertNotNull(userRepository);
        }

        @Test
        public void createUser() {
                User user = dg.getUser();
                User createdUser = userRepository.create(user);

                qUser.setUserIdCriteria(dg.getLastUsers().get(0).getUserId());
                userRepository.find(qUser);
                assertEquals(1, qUser.getResult().size());
                assertEquals(qUser.getResult().get(0), createdUser);
        }

// ..
}

@Stateless
@LocalBean
//@RolesAllowed({ "RegisteredUsers" })
//@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class CarRepository implements GenericRepository<Car, Long> {
        @PersistenceContext
        private EntityManager em;

        public CarRepository() {
        }

        @Override
        public Car create(Car car) {
                em.persist(car);
                return car;
        }

        @Override
        public Car modify(Car car) {
                Car mergedCar = em.merge(car);
                return mergedCar;
        }

// ..
}

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class UserRepository implements GenericRepository<User, String> {
        @PersistenceContext
        private EntityManager em;

        public UserRepository() {
        }

        @Override
        public User create(User user) {
                em.persist(user);
                return user;
        }

        @Override
        public User modify(User user) {
                // em.find(User.class, user.getUserId());
                User mergedUser = em.merge(user);
                return mergedUser;
        }
// ..
}
```

// Error log:

```
testCreateNewCar(se.while_se.service.jpa.CarRepositoryTest)  Time elapsed: 0.976 sec  <<< ERROR!
javax.ejb.EJBException: Transaction aborted
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.discoverUnregisteredNewObjects(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:304)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.calculateChanges(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:702)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1490)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.issueSQLbeforeCompletion(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3143)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.issueSQLbeforeCompletion(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:346)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:157)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.JTASynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(JTASynchronizationListener.java:68)
        at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:435)
        at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.commit(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:855)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5136)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4901)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2045)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1994)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:222)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2124.create(Unknown Source)
        at se.while_se.service.jpa.__EJB31_Generated__CarRepository__Intf____Bean__.create(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:264)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:260)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:111)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:105)
        at se.while_se.service.jpa.CarRepository$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.create(CarRepository$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.java)
        at se.while_se.service.jpa.CarRepositoryTest.testCreateNewCar(CarRepositoryTest.java:38)


Results :

Tests in error:
  CarRepositoryTest.testCreateNewCar:38 » EJB Transaction aborted

Tests run: 7, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
```

Comment: Can you post the source for your entities?

Comment: What is line 38 of the CarRepositoryTest?